# Sharing dependencies not in central repo with the project

Tags: maven

I understand how to add local JARs not in Maven's central repo to allow them to be used in my project as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955695/1968462).

However, I'm not sure how I'm going to distribute the project for others to use like this. In the past, I merely had an Eclipse project that included local JARs and those JARs were distributed with the project (in its git repo).

If I use Maven, I'd have to add these local JARs to the local repository, which is in a different location from the project.

So how do I make my project easy to build with these local JARs in mind? Do I just tell the user how to add them to the local repo? Is there a better solution?

Ideally, users would clone my git repo and merely have to run `mvn install` without having to do ANYTHING with dependencies. The dependencies should be my problem, not my users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. You could do that, by creating local repo and adding this repo to git repository.
I guess it's better than ask user to install it by themselves.

For concrete example take a look on my project with local repo - https://github.com/MysterionRise/mavenized-jcuda